# Need help on LFS-7.10 Pass2 binutils configure error

Tags: linux-from-scratch

I have been working on resolving issues in build scripts that were built based on LFS a few years

back. I tried over the last week and tried multiple versions and solutions from different sites.

Learned a lot as I put more effort. I need your help as I couldn't get the reason behind the issue.

Based on LFS, pass 1 completed and dummy.c file execution was a success. Then I get the error in

binutils in pass 2.

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/7.10-systemd/chapter05/binutils-pass2.html GCC 6.2.0
binutils 2.27
glibc 2.24

Edit:

Let me try with a recent version of LFS as suggested
train@ubuntu:~$ uname -a Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-112-generic #113~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 04:37:08

UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux train@ubuntu:~$ gcc --version gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-

6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609 train@ubuntu:~$ ldd --version ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu11.2)

2.23

train@ubuntu:~$ gcc dummy.c train@ubuntu:~$ readelf -l a.out | grep linux [Requesting program

interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2] train@ubuntu:~$ /tools/bin/x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc dummy.c

train@ubuntu:~$ readelf -l a.out | grep linux [Requesting program interpreter: /tools/lib64/ld-linux-

x86-64.so.2]

cd binutils-2.27-compile; CXXFLAGS="-O2 -m64 -fPIC" CFLAGS="-O2 -m64 -fPIC" CC=x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc

AR=x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-ar RANLIB=x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-ranlib ../binutils-2.27/configure --prefix=/tools

******* Contents from config log **************

configure:2297: checking build system type
configure:2311: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2358: checking host system type
configure:2371: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2391: checking target system type
configure:2404: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2458: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2526: result: /usr/bin//install -c
configure:2537: checking whether ln works
configure:2559: result: yes
configure:2563: checking whether ln -s works
configure:2567: result: yes
configure:2574: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:2638: result: /bin/sed
configure:2647: checking for gawk
configure:2663: found /usr/bin//gawk
configure:2674: result: gawk
configure:4121: checking for gcc
configure:4148: result: x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc
configure:4377: checking for C compiler version
configure:4386: x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc --version >&5
x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 6.2.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4397: $? = 0
configure:4386: x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.

COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc

COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/train/swe/distrib/tools/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-tc-linux-gnu/6.2.0/lto-

wrapper

Target: x86_64-tc-linux-gnu

Configured with: ../gcc-6.2.0/configure --prefix=/tools --target=x86_64-tc-linux-gnu --prefix=/tools

--with-sysroot=/home/train/swe/distrib --with-newlib --without-headers --with-local-prefix=/tools --

with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-multilib --

disable-decimal-float --disable-threads --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libatomic --

disable-libstdcxx --disable-libmpx --disable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --disable-libquadmath --enable-

languages=c,c++

Thread model: single

gcc version 6.2.0 (GCC)

configure:4397: $? = 0

configure:4386: x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc -V >&5
x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

configure:4397: $? = 1

configure:4386: x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc -qversion >&5

x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--

version'?

x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

configure:4397: $? = 1

configure:4417: checking for C compiler default output file name

configure:4439: x86_64-tc-linux-gnu-gcc -O2 -m64 -fPIC   conftest.c  >&5
configure:4443: $? = 0

configure:4480: result: a.out

configure:4496: checking whether the C compiler works

configure:4505: ./a.out

../binutils-2.27/
configure: line 4507: 87493 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./$ac_file

configure:4509: $? = 139

configure:4516: error: in `/home/train/swe/distrib/build/sources/binutils/binutils-2.27-compile':

configure:4520: error: cannot run C compiled programs.

If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'. See` config.log' for more details.

Would appreciate any help on this

Comment: Please format your above output... Have you considered switching to the latest stable version of LFS? What is `binutils-2.27-compile`?

Comment: Thanks. Let me try recent stable LFS. Please advise me should I delete this post.